# CN1: Gradient with alpha channel

Tags: codenameone

[image: composition with gradient]

I would like to have a gradient which goes from black to transparent (not white). How can I achieve this?

From my attempt below I assume the gradient style color's alpha value is not considered:

```
    gui_Footer.allStyles.apply {
        backgroundType = Style.BACKGROUND_GRADIENT_LINEAR_VERTICAL
        border = RoundRectBorder.create().topOnlyMode(true).cornerRadius(1f)
        backgroundGradientEndColor = ColorUtil.BLACK
        backgroundGradientStartColor = ColorUtil.argb(0, 255, 255, 255)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradients in Codename One ignore the alpha byte. While we could technically add support for alpha gradients it's not something that's planned at this time. You can probably generate such an image by manipulating the RGB data but it would be more efficient to just generate an RGB image of a gradient and draw it scaled.

Notice that this is generally the most efficient approach since the GPU works by drawing textures very efficiently. If an image is a power of 2 (e.g. 256x128 pixels) it can fit perfectly in a texture and it's drawn very fast. Much faster than our builtin gradients.